# Access nested Json data with PHP

Tags: php, json

If I do a print_r($jasonArray); I get the following:

```
Array
(
    [lista_viaje_ida] => Array
        (
            [TITULO] => Seleccione su viaje de ida
            [ID_VIAJE_SENTIDO] => 1
            [ITINERARIOS] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [ID_RUTA] => 1
                        [NOM_RUTA] => OLLANTAYTAMBO - MACHU PICCHU
                        [ABR_RUTA] => OLLA - MAPI
                        [ID_VIAJE_SENTIDO] => 1
                        [ID_SERVICIO] => 1
                        [NOM_SERVICIO] => FIRST CLASS
                        [FEC_VIAJE] => 01/05/2017
                        [ID_FRECUENCIA] => 3
                        [NUM_FRECUENCIA] => 43
                        [HOR_SALIDA] => 11:15
                        [HOR_LLEGADA] => 12:45
                        [ID_CONVOY] => 20201
                        [NUM_CUPO_DISPONIBLE] => 22
                        [NUM_SALIDA] => 34523452353
                        [ID_VIAJE_TIPO] => 2
                        [NUM_CUPO_ADULTO] => 1
                        [NUM_CUPO_NINO] => 1
                        [IMP_PRECIO_ADULTO] => 121.00
                        [IMP_PRECIO_NINO] => 50.00
                        [IMP_PAGO_TIPO_CAMBIO] => 1
                        [COD_ISO_MONEDA_PAGO] => USD
                        [IND_SELECCIONAR] => 1
                        [IND_OFERTA] => 0
                        [NOM_ESTADO] => ¡Disponible!
                        [DES_ESTADO] => !Disponible!
                        [MENSAJE_ASIENTO] => 
                    )
                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [ID_RUTA] => 3
                        [NOM_RUTA] => POROY - MACHU PICCHU
                        [ABR_RUTA] => POROY - MAPI
                        [ID_VIAJE_SENTIDO] => 1
                        [ID_SERVICIO] => 2
                        [NOM_SERVICIO] => EXECUTIVE CLASS
                        [FEC_VIAJE] => 01/05/2017
                        [ID_FRECUENCIA] => 11
                        [NUM_FRECUENCIA] => 61
                        [HOR_SALIDA] => 05:55
                        [HOR_LLEGADA] => 08:48
                        [ID_CONVOY] => 20206
                        [NUM_CUPO_DISPONIBLE] => 57
                        [NUM_SALIDA] => 34523452353
                        [ID_VIAJE_TIPO] => 2
                        [NUM_CUPO_ADULTO] => 1
                        [NUM_CUPO_NINO] => 1
                        [IMP_PRECIO_ADULTO] => 77.00
                        [IMP_PRECIO_NINO] => 33.00
                        [IMP_PAGO_TIPO_CAMBIO] => 1
                        [COD_ISO_MONEDA_PAGO] => USD
                        [IND_SELECCIONAR] => 1
                        [IND_OFERTA] => 0
                        [NOM_ESTADO] => ¡Disponible!
                        [DES_ESTADO] => !Disponible!
                        [MENSAJE_ASIENTO] => 
                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [ID_RUTA] => 1
                        [NOM_RUTA] => OLLANTAYTAMBO - MACHU PICCHU
                        [ABR_RUTA] => OLLA - MAPI
                        [ID_VIAJE_SENTIDO] => 1
                        [ID_SERVICIO] => 2
                        [NOM_SERVICIO] => EXECUTIVE CLASS
                        [FEC_VIAJE] => 01/05/2017
                        [ID_FRECUENCIA] => 1
                        [NUM_FRECUENCIA] => 41
                        [HOR_SALIDA] => 06:40
                        [HOR_LLEGADA] => 08:01
                        [ID_CONVOY] => 20199
                        [NUM_CUPO_DISPONIBLE] => 96
                        [NUM_SALIDA] => 34523452353
                        [ID_VIAJE_TIPO] => 2
                        [NUM_CUPO_ADULTO] => 1
                        [NUM_CUPO_NINO] => 1
                        [IMP_PRECIO_ADULTO] => 66.00
                        [IMP_PRECIO_NINO] => 33.00
                        [IMP_PAGO_TIPO_CAMBIO] => 1
                        [COD_ISO_MONEDA_PAGO] => USD
                        [IND_SELECCIONAR] => 1
                        [IND_OFERTA] => 0
                        [NOM_ESTADO] => ¡Disponible!
                        [DES_ESTADO] => !Disponible!
                        [MENSAJE_ASIENTO] => 
                    )

                [3] => Array
                    (
                        [ID_RUTA] => 1
                        [NOM_RUTA] => OLLANTAYTAMBO - MACHU PICCHU
                        [ABR_RUTA] => OLLA - MAPI
                        [ID_VIAJE_SENTIDO] => 1
                        [ID_SERVICIO] => 2
                        [NOM_SERVICIO] => EXECUTIVE CLASS
                        [FEC_VIAJE] => 01/05/2017
                        [ID_FRECUENCIA] => 11
                        [NUM_FRECUENCIA] => 61
                        [HOR_SALIDA] => 07:20
                        [HOR_LLEGADA] => 08:48
                        [ID_CONVOY] => 20206
                        [NUM_CUPO_DISPONIBLE] => 35
                        [NUM_SALIDA] => 34523452353
                        [ID_VIAJE_TIPO] => 2
                        [NUM_CUPO_ADULTO] => 1
                        [NUM_CUPO_NINO] => 1
                        [IMP_PRECIO_ADULTO] => 68.00
                        [IMP_PRECIO_NINO] => 33.00
                        [IMP_PAGO_TIPO_CAMBIO] => 1
                        [COD_ISO_MONEDA_PAGO] => USD
                        [IND_SELECCIONAR] => 1
                        [IND_OFERTA] => 0
                        [NOM_ESTADO] => ¡Disponible!
                        [DES_ESTADO] => !Disponible!
                        [MENSAJE_ASIENTO] => 
                    )

                [4] => Array
                    (
                        [ID_RUTA] => 1
                        [NOM_RUTA] => OLLANTAYTAMBO - MACHU PICCHU
                        [ABR_RUTA] => OLLA - MAPI
                        [ID_VIAJE_SENTIDO] => 1
                        [ID_SERVICIO] => 2
                        [NOM_SERVICIO] => EXECUTIVE CLASS
                        [FEC_VIAJE] => 01/05/2017
                        [ID_FRECUENCIA] => 3
                        [NUM_FRECUENCIA] => 43
                        [HOR_SALIDA] => 11:15
                        [HOR_LLEGADA] => 12:45
                        [ID_CONVOY] => 20201
                        [NUM_CUPO_DISPONIBLE] => 93
                        [NUM_SALIDA] => 34523452353
                        [ID_VIAJE_TIPO] => 2
                        [NUM_CUPO_ADULTO] => 1
                        [NUM_CUPO_NINO] => 1
                        [IMP_PRECIO_ADULTO] => 61.00
                        [IMP_PRECIO_NINO] => 33.00
                        [IMP_PAGO_TIPO_CAMBIO] => 1
                        [COD_ISO_MONEDA_PAGO] => USD
                        [IND_SELECCIONAR] => 1
                        [IND_OFERTA] => 0
                        [NOM_ESTADO] => ¡Disponible!
                        [DES_ESTADO] => !Disponible!
                        [MENSAJE_ASIENTO] => 
                    )

                [5] => Array
                    (
                        [ID_RUTA] => 1
                        [NOM_RUTA] => OLLANTAYTAMBO - MACHU PICCHU
                        [ABR_RUTA] => OLLA - MAPI
                        [ID_VIAJE_SENTIDO] => 1
                        [ID_SERVICIO] => 2
                        [NOM_SERVICIO] => EXECUTIVE CLASS
                        [FEC_VIAJE] => 01/05/2017
                        [ID_FRECUENCIA] => 13
                        [NUM_FRECUENCIA] => 63
                        [HOR_SALIDA] => 11:30
                        [HOR_LLEGADA] => 13:06
                        [ID_CONVOY] => 20208
                        [NUM_CUPO_DISPONIBLE] => 41
                        [NUM_SALIDA] => 34523452353
                        [ID_VIAJE_TIPO] => 2
                        [NUM_CUPO_ADULTO] => 1
                        [NUM_CUPO_NINO] => 1
                        [IMP_PRECIO_ADULTO] => 62.00
                        [IMP_PRECIO_NINO] => 33.00
                        [IMP_PAGO_TIPO_CAMBIO] => 1
                        [COD_ISO_MONEDA_PAGO] => USD
                        [IND_SELECCIONAR] => 1
                        [IND_OFERTA] => 0
                        [NOM_ESTADO] => ¡Disponible!
                        [DES_ESTADO] => !Disponible!
                        [MENSAJE_ASIENTO] => 
                    )

                [6] => Array
                    (
                        [ID_RUTA] => 1
                        [NOM_RUTA] => OLLANTAYTAMBO - MACHU PICCHU
                        [ABR_RUTA] => OLLA - MAPI
                        [ID_VIAJE_SENTIDO] => 1
                        [ID_SERVICIO] => 2
                        [NOM_SERVICIO] => EXECUTIVE CLASS
                        [FEC_VIAJE] => 01/05/2017
                        [ID_FRECUENCIA] => 15
                        [NUM_FRECUENCIA] => 65
                        [HOR_SALIDA] => 12:36
                        [HOR_LLEGADA] => 14:00
                        [ID_CONVOY] => 20210
                        [NUM_CUPO_DISPONIBLE] => 33
                        [NUM_SALIDA] => 34523452353
                        [ID_VIAJE_TIPO] => 2
                        [NUM_CUPO_ADULTO] => 1
                        [NUM_CUPO_NINO] => 1
                        [IMP_PRECIO_ADULTO] => 64.00
                        [IMP_PRECIO_NINO] => 33.00
                        [IMP_PAGO_TIPO_CAMBIO] => 1
                        [COD_ISO_MONEDA_PAGO] => USD
                        [IND_SELECCIONAR] => 1
                        [IND_OFERTA] => 0
                        [NOM_ESTADO] => ¡Disponible!
                        [DES_ESTADO] => !Disponible!
                        [MENSAJE_ASIENTO] => 
                    )

                [7] => Array
                    (
                        [ID_RUTA] => 1
                        [NOM_RUTA] => OLLANTAYTAMBO - MACHU PICCHU
                        [ABR_RUTA] => OLLA - MAPI
                        [ID_VIAJE_SENTIDO] => 1
                        [ID_SERVICIO] => 2
                        [NOM_SERVICIO] => EXECUTIVE CLASS
                        [FEC_VIAJE] => 01/05/2017
                        [ID_FRECUENCIA] => 5
                        [NUM_FRECUENCIA] => 45
                        [HOR_SALIDA] => 16:36
                        [HOR_LLEGADA] => 18:09
                        [ID_CONVOY] => 20203
                        [NUM_CUPO_DISPONIBLE] => 8
                        [NUM_SALIDA] => 34523452353
                        [ID_VIAJE_TIPO] => 2
                        [NUM_CUPO_ADULTO] => 1
                        [NUM_CUPO_NINO] => 1
                        [IMP_PRECIO_ADULTO] => 64.00
                        [IMP_PRECIO_NINO] => 33.00
                        [IMP_PAGO_TIPO_CAMBIO] => 1
                        [COD_ISO_MONEDA_PAGO] => USD
                        [IND_SELECCIONAR] => 1
                        [IND_OFERTA] => 0
                        [NOM_ESTADO] => !Muy solicitado!
                        [DES_ESTADO] => !Disponible!
                        [MENSAJE_ASIENTO] => Quedan 8 asientos
                    )
                [8] => Array
                    (
                        [ID_RUTA] => 1
                        [NOM_RUTA] => OLLANTAYTAMBO - MACHU PICCHU
                        [ABR_RUTA] => OLLA - MAPI
                        [ID_VIAJE_SENTIDO] => 1
                        [ID_SERVICIO] => 2
                        [NOM_SERVICIO] => EXECUTIVE CLASS
                        [FEC_VIAJE] => 01/05/2017
                        [ID_FRECUENCIA] => 17
                        [NUM_FRECUENCIA] => 67
                        [HOR_SALIDA] => 19:27
                        [HOR_LLEGADA] => 21:09
                        [ID_CONVOY] => 20212
                        [NUM_CUPO_DISPONIBLE] => 49
                        [NUM_SALIDA] => 34523452353
                        [ID_VIAJE_TIPO] => 2
                        [NUM_CUPO_ADULTO] => 1
                        [NUM_CUPO_NINO] => 1
                        [IMP_PRECIO_ADULTO] => 65.00
                        [IMP_PRECIO_NINO] => 33.00
                        [IMP_PAGO_TIPO_CAMBIO] => 1
                        [COD_ISO_MONEDA_PAGO] => USD
                        [IND_SELECCIONAR] => 1
                        [IND_OFERTA] => 0
                        [NOM_ESTADO] => ¡Disponible!
                        [DES_ESTADO] => !Disponible!
                        [MENSAJE_ASIENTO] => 
                    )

            )

    )

[lista_viaje_retorno] => Array
    (
        [TITULO] => Seleccione su viaje de retorno
        [ID_VIAJE_SENTIDO] => 2
        [ITINERARIOS] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [ID_RUTA] => 2
                        [NOM_RUTA] => MACHU PICCHU - OLLANTAYTAMBO
                        [ABR_RUTA] => MAPI - OLLA
                        [ID_VIAJE_SENTIDO] => 2
                        [ID_SERVICIO] => 1
                        [NOM_SERVICIO] => FIRST CLASS
                        [FEC_VIAJE] => 31/05/2017
                        [ID_FRECUENCIA] => 6
                        [NUM_FRECUENCIA] => 46
                        [HOR_SALIDA] => 19:00
                        [HOR_LLEGADA] => 20:32
                        [ID_CONVOY] => 20624
                        [NUM_CUPO_DISPONIBLE] => 16
                        [NUM_SALIDA] => 34523452353
                        [ID_VIAJE_TIPO] => 2
                        [NUM_CUPO_ADULTO] => 1
                        [NUM_CUPO_NINO] => 1
                        [IMP_PRECIO_ADULTO] => 121.00
                        [IMP_PRECIO_NINO] => 50.00
                        [IMP_PAGO_TIPO_CAMBIO] => 1
                        [COD_ISO_MONEDA_PAGO] => USD
                        [IND_SELECCIONAR] => 1
                        [IND_OFERTA] => 0
                        [NOM_ESTADO] => ¡Disponible!
                        [DES_ESTADO] => !Disponible!
                        [MENSAJE_ASIENTO] => 
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [ID_RUTA] => 2
                        [NOM_RUTA] => MACHU PICCHU - OLLANTAYTAMBO
                        [ABR_RUTA] => MAPI - OLLA
                        [ID_VIAJE_SENTIDO] => 2
                        [ID_SERVICIO] => 2
                        [NOM_SERVICIO] => EXECUTIVE CLASS
                        [FEC_VIAJE] => 31/05/2017
                        [ID_FRECUENCIA] => 2
                        [NUM_FRECUENCIA] => 42
                        [HOR_SALIDA] => 08:30
                        [HOR_LLEGADA] => 10:10
                        [ID_CONVOY] => 20620
                        [NUM_CUPO_DISPONIBLE] => 97
                        [NUM_SALIDA] => 34523452353
                        [ID_VIAJE_TIPO] => 2
                        [NUM_CUPO_ADULTO] => 1
                        [NUM_CUPO_NINO] => 1
                        [IMP_PRECIO_ADULTO] => 54.00
                        [IMP_PRECIO_NINO] => 33.00
                        [IMP_PAGO_TIPO_CAMBIO] => 1
                        [COD_ISO_MONEDA_PAGO] => USD
                        [IND_SELECCIONAR] => 1
                        [IND_OFERTA] => 0
                        [NOM_ESTADO] => ¡Disponible!
                        [DES_ESTADO] => !Disponible!
                        [MENSAJE_ASIENTO] => 
                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [ID_RUTA] => 2
                        [NOM_RUTA] => MACHU PICCHU - OLLANTAYTAMBO
                        [ABR_RUTA] => MAPI - OLLA
                        [ID_VIAJE_SENTIDO] => 2
                        [ID_SERVICIO] => 2
                        [NOM_SERVICIO] => EXECUTIVE CLASS
                        [FEC_VIAJE] => 31/05/2017
                        [ID_FRECUENCIA] => 12
                        [NUM_FRECUENCIA] => 62
                        [HOR_SALIDA] => 10:32
                        [HOR_LLEGADA] => 12:09
                        [ID_CONVOY] => 20627
                        [NUM_CUPO_DISPONIBLE] => 201
                        [NUM_SALIDA] => 34523452353
                        [ID_VIAJE_TIPO] => 2
                        [NUM_CUPO_ADULTO] => 1
                        [NUM_CUPO_NINO] => 1
                        [IMP_PRECIO_ADULTO] => 55.00
                        [IMP_PRECIO_NINO] => 33.00
                        [IMP_PAGO_TIPO_CAMBIO] => 1
                        [COD_ISO_MONEDA_PAGO] => USD
                        [IND_SELECCIONAR] => 1
                        [IND_OFERTA] => 0
                        [NOM_ESTADO] => ¡Disponible!
                        [DES_ESTADO] => !Disponible!
                        [MENSAJE_ASIENTO] => 
                    )

                [3] => Array
                    (
                        [ID_RUTA] => 2
                        [NOM_RUTA] => MACHU PICCHU - OLLANTAYTAMBO
                        [ABR_RUTA] => MAPI - OLLA
                        [ID_VIAJE_SENTIDO] => 2
                        [ID_SERVICIO] => 2
                        [NOM_SERVICIO] => EXECUTIVE CLASS
                        [FEC_VIAJE] => 31/05/2017
                        [ID_FRECUENCIA] => 4
                        [NUM_FRECUENCIA] => 44
                        [HOR_SALIDA] => 14:30
                        [HOR_LLEGADA] => 15:56
                        [ID_CONVOY] => 20622
                        [NUM_CUPO_DISPONIBLE] => 20
                        [NUM_SALIDA] => 34523452353
                        [ID_VIAJE_TIPO] => 2
                        [NUM_CUPO_ADULTO] => 1
                        [NUM_CUPO_NINO] => 1
                        [IMP_PRECIO_ADULTO] => 67.00
                        [IMP_PRECIO_NINO] => 33.00
                        [IMP_PAGO_TIPO_CAMBIO] => 1
                        [COD_ISO_MONEDA_PAGO] => USD
                        [IND_SELECCIONAR] => 1
                        [IND_OFERTA] => 0
                        [NOM_ESTADO] => ¡Disponible!
                        [DES_ESTADO] => !Disponible!
                        [MENSAJE_ASIENTO] => 
                    )

                [4] => Array
                    (
                        [ID_RUTA] => 2
                        [NOM_RUTA] => MACHU PICCHU - OLLANTAYTAMBO
                        [ABR_RUTA] => MAPI - OLLA
                        [ID_VIAJE_SENTIDO] => 2
                        [ID_SERVICIO] => 2
                        [NOM_SERVICIO] => EXECUTIVE CLASS
                        [FEC_VIAJE] => 31/05/2017
                        [ID_FRECUENCIA] => 14
                        [NUM_FRECUENCIA] => 64
                        [HOR_SALIDA] => 16:12
                        [HOR_LLEGADA] => 17:50
                        [ID_CONVOY] => 20629
                        [NUM_CUPO_DISPONIBLE] => 1
                        [NUM_SALIDA] => 34523452353
                        [ID_VIAJE_TIPO] => 2
                        [NUM_CUPO_ADULTO] => 1
                        [NUM_CUPO_NINO] => 1
                        [IMP_PRECIO_ADULTO] => 77.00
                        [IMP_PRECIO_NINO] => 33.00
                        [IMP_PAGO_TIPO_CAMBIO] => 1
                        [COD_ISO_MONEDA_PAGO] => USD
                        [IND_SELECCIONAR] => 0
                        [IND_OFERTA] => 0
                        [NOM_ESTADO] => !Muy solicitado! Quedan 1 asientos
                        [DES_ESTADO] => !Muy solicitado!
                        [MENSAJE_ASIENTO] => 
                    )

                [5] => Array
                    (
                        [ID_RUTA] => 4
                        [NOM_RUTA] => MACHU PICCHU - POROY
                        [ABR_RUTA] => MAPI - POROY
                        [ID_VIAJE_SENTIDO] => 2
                        [ID_SERVICIO] => 2
                        [NOM_SERVICIO] => EXECUTIVE CLASS
                        [FEC_VIAJE] => 31/05/2017
                        [ID_FRECUENCIA] => 14
                        [NUM_FRECUENCIA] => 64
                        [HOR_SALIDA] => 16:12
                        [HOR_LLEGADA] => 19:38
                        [ID_CONVOY] => 20629
                        [NUM_CUPO_DISPONIBLE] => 1
                        [NUM_SALIDA] => 34523452353
                        [ID_VIAJE_TIPO] => 2
                        [NUM_CUPO_ADULTO] => 1
                        [NUM_CUPO_NINO] => 1
                        [IMP_PRECIO_ADULTO] => 90.00
                        [IMP_PRECIO_NINO] => 33.00
                        [IMP_PAGO_TIPO_CAMBIO] => 1
                        [COD_ISO_MONEDA_PAGO] => USD
                        [IND_SELECCIONAR] => 0
                        [IND_OFERTA] => 0
                        [NOM_ESTADO] => !Muy solicitado! Quedan 1 asientos
                        [DES_ESTADO] => !Muy solicitado!
                        [MENSAJE_ASIENTO] => 
                    )

                [6] => Array
                    (
                        [ID_RUTA] => 2
                        [NOM_RUTA] => MACHU PICCHU - OLLANTAYTAMBO
                        [ABR_RUTA] => MAPI - OLLA
                        [ID_VIAJE_SENTIDO] => 2
                        [ID_SERVICIO] => 2
                        [NOM_SERVICIO] => EXECUTIVE CLASS
                        [FEC_VIAJE] => 31/05/2017
                        [ID_FRECUENCIA] => 6
                        [NUM_FRECUENCIA] => 46
                        [HOR_SALIDA] => 19:00
                        [HOR_LLEGADA] => 20:32
                        [ID_CONVOY] => 20624
                        [NUM_CUPO_DISPONIBLE] => 36
                        [NUM_SALIDA] => 34523452353
                        [ID_VIAJE_TIPO] => 2
                        [NUM_CUPO_ADULTO] => 1
                        [NUM_CUPO_NINO] => 1
                        [IMP_PRECIO_ADULTO] => 68.00
                        [IMP_PRECIO_NINO] => 33.00
                        [IMP_PAGO_TIPO_CAMBIO] => 1
                        [COD_ISO_MONEDA_PAGO] => USD
                        [IND_SELECCIONAR] => 1
                        [IND_OFERTA] => 0
                        [NOM_ESTADO] => ¡Disponible!
                        [DES_ESTADO] => !Disponible!
                        [MENSAJE_ASIENTO] => 
                    )

                [7] => Array
                    (
                        [ID_RUTA] => 2
                        [NOM_RUTA] => MACHU PICCHU - OLLANTAYTAMBO
                        [ABR_RUTA] => MAPI - OLLA
                        [ID_VIAJE_SENTIDO] => 2
                        [ID_SERVICIO] => 2
                        [NOM_SERVICIO] => EXECUTIVE CLASS
                        [FEC_VIAJE] => 31/05/2017
                        [ID_FRECUENCIA] => 16
                        [NUM_FRECUENCIA] => 66
                        [HOR_SALIDA] => 20:20
                        [HOR_LLEGADA] => 21:59
                        [ID_CONVOY] => 20631
                        [NUM_CUPO_DISPONIBLE] => 31
                        [NUM_SALIDA] => 34523452353
                        [ID_VIAJE_TIPO] => 2
                        [NUM_CUPO_ADULTO] => 1
                        [NUM_CUPO_NINO] => 1
                        [IMP_PRECIO_ADULTO] => 62.00
                        [IMP_PRECIO_NINO] => 33.00
                        [IMP_PAGO_TIPO_CAMBIO] => 1
                        [COD_ISO_MONEDA_PAGO] => USD
                        [IND_SELECCIONAR] => 1
                        [IND_OFERTA] => 0
                        [NOM_ESTADO] => ¡Disponible!
                        [DES_ESTADO] => !Disponible!
                        [MENSAJE_ASIENTO] => 
                    )

                [8] => Array
                    (
                        [ID_RUTA] => 2
                        [NOM_RUTA] => MACHU PICCHU - OLLANTAYTAMBO
                        [ABR_RUTA] => MAPI - OLLA
                        [ID_VIAJE_SENTIDO] => 2
                        [ID_SERVICIO] => 2
                        [NOM_SERVICIO] => EXECUTIVE CLASS
                        [FEC_VIAJE] => 31/05/2017
                        [ID_FRECUENCIA] => 8
                        [NUM_FRECUENCIA] => 48
                        [HOR_SALIDA] => 21:30
                        [HOR_LLEGADA] => 22:54
                        [ID_CONVOY] => 20625
                        [NUM_CUPO_DISPONIBLE] => 88
                        [NUM_SALIDA] => 34523452353
                        [ID_VIAJE_TIPO] => 2
                        [NUM_CUPO_ADULTO] => 1
                        [NUM_CUPO_NINO] => 1
                        [IMP_PRECIO_ADULTO] => 62.00
                        [IMP_PRECIO_NINO] => 33.00
                        [IMP_PAGO_TIPO_CAMBIO] => 1
                        [COD_ISO_MONEDA_PAGO] => USD
                        [IND_SELECCIONAR] => 1
                        [IND_OFERTA] => 0
                        [NOM_ESTADO] => ¡Disponible!
                        [DES_ESTADO] => !Disponible!
                        [MENSAJE_ASIENTO] => 
                    )

            )

    )
```

)

How do I loop through the array so that I get the value of [NOM_SERVICIO]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this hope this will help you out.

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/782168) `Here i have used the json of your print_r($jasonArray);`

```
$result=  array_merge($result,  array_column($array["lista_viaje_ida"]["ITINERARIOS"], "NOM_SERVICIO"));
$result=  array_merge($result,  array_column($array["lista_viaje_retorno"]["ITINERARIOS"], "NOM_SERVICIO"));
print_r($result);
```

**Solution 2:**`for manually looping over the content`

```
foreach($array["lista_viaje_ida"]["ITINERARIOS"] as $value)
{
    echo $value["NOM_SERVICIO"].PHP_EOL; 
    echo $value["NUM_FRECUENCIA"].PHP_EOL; 
}

foreach($array["lista_viaje_retorno"]["ITINERARIOS"] as $value)
{
    echo $value["NOM_SERVICIO"].PHP_EOL; 
    echo $value["NUM_FRECUENCIA"].PHP_EOL; 
}
```

Comment: @FrankMorrison Okay no issues i am updating my post to get it done.

Comment: Your code worked but I need to loop through the ["lista_viaje_ida"]["ITINERARIOS"] to output an html table and then do the same with ["lista_viaje_retorno"]["ITINERARIOS"]

Comment: try this https://eval.in/782177 Hope this will work fine, within the loop you can do what you want.

Comment: Very close, I also want to output other data inside ITINERARIOS like "NUM_FRECUENCIA"

Answer (score 0):

Assuming an array returned by `json_deocde()`, something like the following should work

```
for($i in $jsonArray){
    print($i->{NOM_SERVICIO};
}
```

See the [PHP doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

```
$decodeArr = json_decode($jasonArray)
foreach($decodeArr['lista_viaje_ida']['ITINERARIOS'] as $key=>$value){

echo $value['NOM_SERVICIO'].'<br>';

}
```

you can access by decode the json using **json_decode** function and applying **foreach** loop on  **$decodeArr['lista_viaje_ida']['ITINERARIOS']**